# How to find duplicates row wise in multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've dataframe with unknown columns. I need to find duplicates in column which start with **OEInterestTraceData** and only if they are more than 1 in column. Also need to assign 1 new variable/flag if they are duplicate in row then 1 else 0.

```
W_Interest = loaddata1.loc[:, loaddata1.columns.str.contains('OEInterestTraceData')]

if len(W_Interest.columns) > 1:
    if W_Interest[W_Interest.duplicated(keep=False)]:
        W_Interest[['dummy']] = 1
    else:
        W_Interest[['dummy']] = 0
else:
    W_Interest[['dummy']] = 0
```

right now it is giving me below error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Output should be like this:
[image]

Please help out if you have any better solutions.

Comment: Please post an MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a column of zeros first, then mark those duplicated rows with value 1, for example:

```
W_Interest = loaddata1.loc[:, loaddata1.columns.str.contains('OEInterestTraceData')]

if len(W_Interest.columns) > 1:
    W_Interest['dummy'] = 0    #assign zero to all rows first
    W_Interest.loc[W_Interest.duplicated(keep=False), 'dummy'] = 1    #then for those rows that are duplicated assign 1 
else:
    W_Interest['dummy'] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It got run but still not flagging 1 for duplicates in row throughout columns. Please suggest.

Comment: However, I've also tried .column.duplicated still giving me error.

`W_Interest = loaddata1.loc[:, loaddata1.columns.str.contains('OEInterestTraceData')]`


`if len(W_Interest.columns) > 1:`


    `W_Interest['dummy'] = 0    #assign zero to all rows first`

    `W_Interest.loc[W_Interest.columns.duplicated(keep=False), 'dummy'] = 1`    #then for those rows that are duplicated assign 1

`else:`

    `W_Interest['dummy'] = 0`


Error - IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 4 instead of 5

Comment: specify the column name if you're looking for duplication in a specific column, for example `W_Interest.loc[W_Interest.OEInterestTraceData2.duplicated(keep=False), 'dummy'] = 1`

Comment: have you resolved your question?